# Кэширование и производительность

Tags: java, кэширование

Допустим, в приложении два поля для ввода значений и одна кнопка по нажатию на которую проходит долгий расчет результата с несколькими длинными циклами, который длится около 3-4 секунд.
Есть ли смысл кэшировать результат, например при закрытии приложения писать сериализованный HashMap с кэшем в файл, а при запуске приложения из этого файла кэш считывать и во время выполнения программы проверять кэш на наличие запрашиваемого результата и, если его нет только тогда считать с помощью циклов и т.д.? В кэш писать, например, 10000 значений.
Интересно мнение специалистов даст ли такое кэширование заметный прирост производительности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Манипуляции с кэшами - это дополнительная работа, дополнительный код, который нужно поддерживать. Манипуляции по сериализации-десериализации - тем более. Кроме того, это может усложнять старт-стоп и вообще обслуживание приложения создавая лишнюю нагрузку на саппорт.

Лично мне почему-то кажется, что достаточно сделать обычный кэш в памяти на сколько-нибудь значений. Первые пользователи будут получать небольшие задержки, но со временем всё устаканится. Если же вероятность повторов невелика, то и вовсе незачем кэшировать.

Разве что количество комбинаций входных данных ограничено и тогда можно не кэшировать, а вычислить их заранее и заготовить файл с результатами вычислений, чтобы потом всегда читать их. Но, как я понимаю, это не тот случай.

UPD: есть правда ещё один фактор, влияющий на принятие решения: как часто будет осуществляться перезапуск сервера или редеплой приложения. Если очень очень часто, вариантов много, пользователей много, а повторяемость ни то ни сё, то возможно будет иметь смысл делать сериализацию..

Comment: Если не углубляться, то в Java сериализация осуществляется посредством Serialization API, которые практически не требует усилий разработчика - так что это не проблема.
И да, заготовить файл с готовыми решениями не получится из-за огромного количества входящих комбинаций.
А так я согласен с вами.

Comment: Потребуется работа по конфигурированию приложения (путь к месту, где хранить всё это), работа по отлову старт-стопа, саппорту придётся стопать сервер только аккуратно (нельзя будет kill -9). Сам факт наличия какого-то конфига всё усложняет. В общем, поинт в том, что не стоит платить на что-то, что может и не стоит затрат, даже если они кажутся небольшими.

Answer (score 1):

стоит/не стоит зависит только от того как часто будет перезапускатся приложение и насколько сложная операция иницаилизации. обычно в маленьких приложениях достаточно использования ленивой инициализации:

```
class MyCache
{
   private final Map < Object, Object > cache = new HashMap < Object, Object > ();

   public Object getValue ( final Object key )
   {
      Object value = cache.get ( key );
      if ( null == value )
      {
         value = calculateValue ( key );
         cache.put ( key, value );
      }

      return value;
   }

   private Object calculateValue ( final Object key )
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

когда ваше приложение достаточно "выростет" тогда стоит обратить внимание в сторону уже готовых решений (напр. ehcache). но даже в этом случае лучше проанализировать профайлером затраты на кеширование/вычисление данных

Answer (score 0):

смотря насколько большие объекты вы собираетесь сериализировать и десереализировать - если они по времени все равно меньше - то стоит сериализовать.

Не забудьте про что память не резиновая ... и все совать в кешь нельзя а то ваша программа при запуске читая сериализованные объекты сожрет всю память

Comment: Например 10000 пар double значений, не думаю, что это страшная потеря для памяти. 
Но для себя я пока принял решение не усложнять себе жизнь и менять код только в случае необходимости. Сейчас этой необходимости нет и программа без кеширования работает нормально.